# eclipse default font in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, fonts

I have asked this question on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224577/eclipse-default-font-in-ubuntu-12-04) thinking that it may be related to *ubuntu* but now that I think about it, it may rather be related to *eclipse* so I wanted to ask in here as well.

I'm using eclipse on my ubuntu 12.04 system. Currently the default font in eclipse is set to `monospace` (mostly) although my system monospace font defaults to `ubuntu mono` (checked from gnome-tweak-tool). I have found [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-20.htm) in the eclipse documentation where it says

> By default, the Workbench uses the fonts and colors provided by the operating system. However, there are a number of ways that this behavior can be customized.

I was wondering why eclipse is not using my system fonts. I can change the font from the preferences but there are a lot of different font settings for different places and I am using a few different eclipse's on my system so it would be nice to find something that would work globally.